# Are the subspaces corresponding to Jordan blocks unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace, generalized-eigenvector

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a complex vector space $V$, where $n<\infty$, and let $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be the Jordan blocks of the matrix of $T$ with respect to some Jordan basis. For each $A_i$ (of size $d\times d$), there is a natural associated subspace $U_i\subseteq V$ (of dimension $d$) for which $\mathcal M(T|_{U_i})=A_i$.

We can decompose $V$ as

$$V=U_1\oplus\dots \oplus U_m,$$

which is an immediate consequence of the existence (and definition) of a Jordan basis. What is less clear is whether the subspaces $U_i$ are unique, i.e., independent of choice of Jordan basis.

**Are the subspaces $U_i$ (defined above) of dimension at least two unique, i.e., independent of choice of Jordan basis?**

---

Although it is a standard result that the Jordan matrix is unique up to reordering of blocks, this does not guarantee that these subspaces are unique. In fact, as a good warning, they definitely are not if we drop the requirement of considering only subspaces of dimension at least two. (As a counterexample, consider $T=I$ on $\mathbb C^2$ and compare the subspaces for the Jordan bases $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ and $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subspaces are not unique. For instance, consider the transformation with matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda&1&0&0\\0&\lambda&0&0\\0&0&\lambda&1\\0&0&0&\lambda}.
$$
Note that the standard basis and the basis 
$$
\{(1,0,-1,0),(0,1,0,-1),(1,0,1,0),(0,1,0,1)\}
$$
are two Jordan bases that lead to distinct subspaces.

Comment: On the other hand, I believe that a similar idea with [Weyr canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyr_canonical_form) yields a unique collection of subspaces

Comment: Thanks. The answer makes sense, and the comment was especially helpful. It seems like the Weyr canonical form provides more clear insight into the structure of the operator's generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: It seems that the subspace associated with the first $n$ Weyr blocks corresponding to $\lambda$ is precisely the subspace $\operatorname{null}(T-\lambda I)^n$, which is certainly independent of a basis.

Comment: @WillG That makes sense. I haven't thought about WCF for a while so I wasn't confident.